# Which table should a foreign key live on

Tags: sql-server

I'm learning about databases. In my very simple database, I have 2 tables.

```
WorkingHoursDetail

ID
NameOfWeek
Hours
```

and

```
WorkingHours

ID
Name
```

As you can see, they currently do not relate.

Now, I'm faced with the question of making them relate. I understand I do this by adding a foreign key, something like MyOtherTableID and linking this to the other tables ID.

In the example above, I could add a foreign key to EITHER

```
WorkingHoursDetail

ID
NameOfWeek
Hours
WorkingHoursId
```

with

```
WorkingHours

ID
Name
```

OR

```
WorkingHoursDetail

ID
NameOfWeek
Hours
```

with

```
WorkingHours

ID
Name
WorkingHoursDetailId
```

I've tried this, and it seems to work but by having this option frightens me. Is there a 'right' answer or will this change only affect the order in which data can be written to the database. If this is the case, then surely this will dictate the flow of the program using it (the users GUI).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should add a foreign key on the child table referencing the parent table. In your case it appears that `WorkingHoursDetail` is the child table and `WorkingHours` the parent table.

You can identify the parent table by asking which table can exists on its own without the presence of the other table. In your case `WorkingHours` can exists without `WorkingHoursDetails` (but not the other way around, so `WorkingHours` appears to be the parent table.

Alternatively you can look at the data flow when inserting new records. If both tables are empty, you should have to insert a row in `WorkingHours` first and then a record in `WorkingHoursDetail`. This makes `WorkingHours` the parent table and therefore the foreign key should be added on `WorkingHoursDetail` referencing `WorkingHours`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer foreign key is used to show up the relation between two or more tables which can be

```
1:1 (One to One), 
1:M (One to Many), 
M:1 (Many to One), 
M:M (Many To Many).
```

In this case if you make **WorkingHour** as your parent table than it can store more than one details in WorkingHourDetails (ie. 1:1 or 1:M) which can be true in real world scenario but if **WorkingHourDetails** is made parent (ie. M:1) than it looks unusual because generally different **WorkingHours** will have its own **WorkingHoursDetails**.

Answer (score 1):

A Simplified Rule of Thumb is to **put the foreign key on the child table (if each parent can have many children)***.

In your example, if:

1. **Each** WorkingHours row can relate to **many** WorkingHoursDetail rows

and

2. **Each** WorkingHoursDetail row can relate to **only one** WorkingHours row

Then:

*WorkingHoursDetail will have the foreign key* referencing the primary key of WorkingHours.

---

*Simplified. See also the original article from 1970: [Codd, E.F. "A relational model of data for large shared data banks"](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~zives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf)